# Is it possible use dynamic fields in istio service mesh?

Tags: istio, servicemesh

Example Web Request : `https://sub.example.com?return_url=blabla.other.com`

I want to process an incoming web request from istio and forward it to the address below with a 302 redirect.

```
if return_url contains "other.com"(this is static) , then 302 Redirect to blabla.other.com
```

`blabla.other.com` can be dynamic value. it can be `abc.other.com, cde.other.com , etc..`